# Test Web service performance using Jmeter in Java

Tags: java, web-services, jmeter, performance-testing

I need to test the performance of a web service method using `Jmeter` in `Java`, i found that `Jmeter` API provide `StandardJMeterEngine` class to run test method by `Jmeter`, and using parameter of type "`String`":

```
public class JMeterTestFromCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jm = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        // jmeter.properties
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("c:/tmp/jmeter.properties");
        HashTree hashTree = new HashTree();
        // HTTP Sampler
        HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
        httpSampler.setDomain("www.google.com");
        httpSampler.setPort(80);
        httpSampler.setPath("/");
        httpSampler.setMethod("GET");
        // Loop Controller
        TestElement loopCtrl = new LoopController();
        ((LoopController) loopCtrl).setLoops(1);
        ((LoopController) loopCtrl).addTestElement(httpSampler);
        ((LoopController) loopCtrl).setFirst(true);
        // Thread Group
        SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController((LoopController) loopCtrl);
        // Test plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("MY TEST PLAN");
        hashTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
        hashTree.add("loopCtrl", loopCtrl);
        hashTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
        hashTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);
        jm.configure(hashTree);
        jm.run();
    }
}
```

my problem is that i'm using a web service of an EJB, this web service uses custom parameters (bean objects), here after how i run it by Soap :

```
String ENDPOINT_ADDRESS = "http://server:8080/server-ejb/MyServiceClass?wsdl";
QName SERVICE_DATA_FINDER = new QName(
    "http://test.service.com/", "MyServiceClass");
javax.xml.ws.Service service;

    service = javax.xml.ws.Service.create(
            new URL(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS), SERVICE_DATA_FINDER);
    IMyServiceClass finder = service.getPort(IMyServiceClass.class);
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    // bean.set...
    // bean.set...
    finder.myMethod("foo", bean);
```

The goal is to create a Maven project that provide an automated performance test for the Web-Service + retrieving test result (that's why i need to implement WS test in Jmeter using Java)

How can i test my web service using StandardJMeterEngine or other API ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you checkout the user manual?

Comment: Which manual user ? do you mean JMeterEngine implementation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any specific reason for testing your service from Java code? JMeter provides [SOAP/XML-RPC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request) Sampler for XML-based web services testing which is more real-life use case.

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide for more details.

However, if testing a web service from Java code is a must, you can just add jar, containing `IMyServiceClass` and dependencies to JMeter's CLASSPATH.

Comment: I want to create a Maven project that provide an automated performance test for the Web-Service + retrieving test result, that's why i need to implement Jmeter test using Java, Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are you aware of JMeter Maven plugin? http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri, that's was a good idea to run web service test from java project, you need to add dependency for the test project (which contains the implementation of web service test), can i apply JMeterMavenPlugin on a test project and get source class of test from the same project ??

Comment: You can configure JMeter classpath via `user.classpath` property

Comment: When i use jmeter-maven-plugin, the process is blocked at line:                          IMyServiceClass finder = service.getPort(IMyServiceClass.class); and when i cancel the execution (type Ctrl+C) the program continues the test and generate the output file (test report)

Comment: Finnaly my solution of performance test of WS by jmeter-maven-plugin is working fine, indeed i should use Jmeter-maven-plugin version 1.8.0 instead of 1.9.0...thanks a lot Dmitri :)